# Journey Builder - Decision Split possibility

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, case

At the beginning of my journey, if the contact has a phone number, I create a case (that will be sent to customer care). 2 days after, I'd like to check the status of that specific case and if it's in status A > exit or if it's in status B > send email.
Is there a way to do this with a Decision Split?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s possible as long as you are synchronizing the Case object along with your Sales/Service Cloud data.
If yes, then it should be already included in the data model and ready to use.

In the Decision split, choose “Contact Data” and find the Case object, then create a filter based on the status.

Contact Data is the most up-to-date data about the contact, which comes directly from Sales/Service Cloud and is synchronized on a time interval which is set in Contact Builder, usually it’s every 15 minutes.

Journey Data represents the state of a contact at the beginning of journey, it doesn’t change over time like Contact data.

You can read more here: [Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

If you need more info on synchronizing data from Sales/Service Cloud, take a look here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/explore-synchronized-data-sources

Comment: You may also need to leverage attribute to attribute comparison

Comment: Thank you for your answer but since there is a one to many relationship between Contact and Case (a contact can have several cases), how is it going to know which case to assess? I'd like him to check the status of the specific case I've created in the previous journey activity.